# Search multiples terms, which are present in different nested documents | Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nested, mapping, ranking

I am trying to get all the documents that have any of the terms present given in the query and higher rank those documents that have most terms in that field, but the field that I am trying to search is nested. So when I try multi_match query it doesn't match more than 1 term in that field. It finds the first match and considers the score of that match and doesn't match the remaining terms to increase the score of that document.

Here is the mapping for the field that I am trying to search:

```
{
    "skills": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer",
            },
            "rating": {
                "type":"byte"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
doc1: {
    skills: [
        {
            name: "HTML",
            rating: 4,
            description: "Whatever..."
        }
    ]
}

doc2: {
    skills: [
        {
            name: "Javascript",
            rating: 5,
            description: "Whatever..."
        }
    ]
}

doc3: {
    skills: [
        {
            name: "HTML",
            rating: 5,
            description: "Whatever..."
        },
        {
            name: "Javascript",
            rating: 4,
            description: "Whatever..."
        },
    ]
}
```

Search Query:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "HTML Javascript",
          "fields": [
            "skills.name"
          ],
          "operator": "or", 
          "type": "most_fields"
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "explain": true
}
```

For eg. When I query "HTML Javascript", for some reason it ranks the document higher which has the last term ('Javascript') and doesn't even look for 'HTML'. I can confirm that the splitting is done properly based on whitespaces, it ranks the document properly when the terms are present in same field and not indifferent nested docs. **What I want is to rank the documents higher which have both 'HTML' and 'Javascript' in this case, doc3 should be ranked higher than doc1 and doc2.**